SwiftData migration crashing with default value
Doing light migration, using default value, rather than optional value for new param does not seems to work and keeps crashing.
I recall an Apple SwiftData migration guide, but it seems to be gone, so I could not find any mention regarding this.
Initial version
@Model
final class Car {
    var timestamp: Date
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

Updated version (using default value)
@Model
final class Car {
    var timestamp: Date
    var engine: Engine = Engine()

    init(timestamp: Date, engine: Engine) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.engine = engine
    }
}

@Model
class Engine {
    var horsepower: Int = 0
    init(horsepower: Int) {
        self.horsepower = horsepower
    }

    init() {
        self.horsepower = 0
    }
}

This crashes: entity=Car, attribute=engine, reason=Validation error missing attribute values on mandatory destination relationship
Using optional
@Model
final class Car {
    var timestamp: Date
    var engine: Engine? // <<< Using optional for new property

    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

This one works.
Here's the migration plan
enum DASchemeV1: VersionedSchema {
    
    static var versionIdentifier: Schema.Version {
        Schema.Version(1, 0, 0)
    }
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Car.self]
    }
    
    @Model
    final class Car {
        var timestamp: Date
        init(timestamp: Date) {
            self.timestamp = timestamp
        }
    }
}

enum DASchemeV2: VersionedSchema {
    
    static var versionIdentifier: Schema.Version {
        Schema.Version(1, 0, 1)
    }
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [
            Car.self,
            Engine.self
        ]
    }
    
    @Model
    final class Car {
        var timestamp: Date
        var engine: Engine = Engine()

        init(timestamp: Date, engine: Engine) {
            self.timestamp = timestamp
            self.engine = engine
        }
    }

    @Model
    class Engine {
        var horsepower: Int = 0
        init(horsepower: Int) {
            self.horsepower = horsepower
        }

        init() {
            self.horsepower = 0
        }
    }
}

struct ItemMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [DASchemeV1.self, DASchemeV2.self]
    }
    
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [migrateV1toV2]
    }

    static let migrateV1toV2 = MigrationStage.lightweight(
        fromVersion: DASchemeV1.self,
        toVersion: DASchemeV2.self
    )
}


Does this means that only optional properties can be added in migration? Or that using a default value needs to do a custom migration?

Edit:
Some information about custom migration as I understand it:
static let migrationV2ToV2 = MigrationStage.custom(
    fromVersion: SchemeV1.self,
    toVersion: SchemeV2.self,
    willMigrate: { context in
        // Context here can read old store: SchemeV1
        let items = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemeV1.Item>())
    }, didMigrate: { context in
        // Context here can read the new store: SchemeV2
        let items = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemeV2.Item>())
    })



Is there a simple example for a migration (light or custom) for adding a non primitive non optional property?
From
@Model
final class User {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

To
@Model
final class Company {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
final class User {
    var name: String
    var company: Company = Company(name: "Example")
    
    init(name: String, company: Company) {
        self.name = name
        self.company = company
    }
}


First of all, if it would’ve worked with a default value here then it would’ve been a lightweight migration without any migration plan needed. I think the underlying problem here is that you need to insert the Engine object into the model context so a default value will never work for a relationship property. So you must do a custom migration here as I see it.

You can add non optional attributes to a SwiftData model in a migration, but to have a default value you must use a custom migration:

What counts as a relationship? That it's not primitive? The main takeaway is that the answer is yes to custom migration.

A relationship is when the type of the property is another model class.

You can add non optional attributes to a SwiftData model in a migration, but to have a default value you must use a custom migration:
 static let migrateV2toV3: MigrationStage = .custom(
        fromVersion: DataSchemaV1.self,
        toVersion: DataSchemaV2.self,
        willMigrate: nil
    ) { context in // didMigrate
        let cars = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<DataSchemaV2.Car>())
        cars.forEach { $0.engine = Engine() }
        try context.save()
    }
}

Unfortunately, adding properties with default values require a custom migration where you set that value. It's not smart enough to both add the new field and populate it with a custom value in light migrations.

The forEach statement does not compile: Cannot assign value of type 'Engine' to type 'DataSchemaV2.Engine'. Removing the encapsulated Car and fetching with FetchDescriptor<Car>() crash with: "Could not create ModelContainer: SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer, _explanation: nil)"

Also, replacing cars.forEach { $0.engine = Engine() } with cars.forEach { $0.engine = .init() }, does compile, but still crashes.

@bauerMusic this is a bit confusing, you say the solution crashes yet you have marked it as accepted? Please understand that an answer could be helpful to others with a similar problem as well so it should be clear that it works properly.

I was 'happy trigger' to mark as solved, only later when I tested it and tweaked it and tried again that I realized that 'as is', it's not working.
